# Crosswalk cordova migration: CordovaApp.java:33: error: cannot find symbol loadUrl(launchUrl)

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I'm doing everything exactely as in instruction: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html

After succesfull build of xwalk_core_library and CordovaLib

Im running cordova build android and facing error:

```
[javac] Compiling 8 source files to D:\myapp\platforms\android\bin\classes
[javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
[javac] D:\myapp\platforms\android\src\com\in2circle\fellor\CordovaApp.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         loadUrl(launchUrl);
[javac]                 ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable launchUrl
[javac]   location: class CordovaApp
[javac] 1 error
```

Crosswalk v 9.38.208.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crosswalk v 9.38.208.10 plays well with Cordova 3.5.*. I have had installed cordova 4.*.

Updated to Crosswalk v 10.39.235.9 and problem was solved.

So use Crosswalk v 10 for Cordova v 4.

Comment: Same error while using cordova 4.2.0 with crosswalk-cordova-11.40.277.7.

Comment: Have you tried crosswalk 12? Tell me if it helps and I'll update my answer.